# How can I install nvidia-331-updates without automatically installing a full-fledged unity desktop?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, package-management, gpu-driver

I'm trying to run XBMC from an ubuntu 14.04 sever install.  In order for my HDMI audio to function properly, I require the latest Nvidia drivers, located in package `nvidia-331-updates`.

Here is the full list of packages that are automatically installed when I run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates`:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apg aptdaemon aspell aspell-en avahi-utils bbswitch-dkms bluez cheese-common
  cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dbus-x11 dconf-cli desktop-file-utils dialog
  diffstat dnsmasq-base enchant evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common gcr gdisk geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gettext gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0
  gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center-shared-data gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-menus
  gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-session-bin
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
  gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-x gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs
  hardening-includes humanity-icon-theme hunspell-en-us hwdata ibus ibus-gtk
  ibus-gtk3 im-config indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound intltool-debian
  iputils-arping libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl
  libarchive13 libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libasprintf-dev
  libauthen-sasl-perl libautodie-perl libavahi-glib1 libavc1394-0
  libcamel-1.2-45 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse
  libcanberra0 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdparanoia0 libcheese-gtk23
  libcheese7 libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango15
  libcogl15 libcrack2 libcroco3 libcuda1-331-updates libdbusmenu-glib4
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdigest-hmac-perl libdv4 libebackend-1.2-7
  libebook-1.2-14 libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libelfg0 libemail-valid-perl
  libenchant1c2a libfftw3-single3 libfile-basedir-perl libgconf-2-4
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata13 libgee2 libgeoclue0
  libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0 libgles2-mesa libglib2.0-bin
  libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome-keyring-common
  libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8
  libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common
  libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libhunspell-1.3-0
  libibus-1.0-5 libical1 libicu52 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7
  libio-pty-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libipc-run-perl
  libipc-system-simple-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblist-moreutils-perl
  libmailtools-perl libmbim-glib0 libmm-glib0 libmnl0 libmtp-common
  libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle4 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1
  libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnotify4 libnspr4
  libnss3 libnss3-nssdb liboauth0 libopenobex1 liborc-0.4-0
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpanel-applet-4-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libperlio-gzip-perl libproxy1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libraw1394-11 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsecret-1-0
  libsecret-common libshout3 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsocket6-perl libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libsub-identify-perl libsystemd-journal0
  libtext-levenshtein-perl libtheora0 libtimezonemap1 libudisks2-0
  libunistring0 libunity-control-center1 liburi-perl liburl-dispatcher1
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xkb1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxklavier16 libyelp0 lightdm lintian
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mousetweaks nautilus-data
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome notification-daemon nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates
  nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates nvidia-prime obex-data-server obexd-client
  p11-kit p11-kit-modules patchutils pptp-linux pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-cairo python-cups
  python-cupshelpers python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-gi python-gnomekeyring
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-libxml2 python-notify
  python-smbc python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-defer
  python3-pkg-resources python3-xdg rtkit session-migration
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond
  sound-theme-freedesktop system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev t1utils
  ubuntu-system-service udisks2 unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon
  usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data yelp yelp-xsl zenity zenity-common
Suggested packages:
  aspell-doc spellutils bumblebee bluez-hcidump evolution
  evolution-data-server-dbg gconf-defaults-service gettext-doc apache2.2-bin
  libapache2-mod-dnssd gvfs-backends-goa samba-common hunspell
  openoffice.org-hunspell openoffice.org-core ibus-clutter ibus-doc ibus-qt4
  click unity-greeter-session-broadcast lrzip libgssapi-perl libcanberra-gtk0
  libdv-bin oss-compat libenchant-voikko libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dev
  gstreamer-codec-install gnome-codec-install gstreamer0.10-tools
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools libraw1394-doc librsvg2-bin
  speex libwww-perl url-dispatcher binutils-multiarch libhtml-parser-perl
  libtext-template-perl libyaml-perl gnome-control-center nautilus
  avahi-autoipd network-manager-openconnect-gnome
  network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-vpnc-gnome
  nvidia-331-updates-uvm pavumeter paman pavucontrol paprefs
  pulseaudio-module-raop pulseaudio-esound-compat python-dbus-doc
  python-dbus-dbg python-gi-cairo python-gobject-2-dbg python-gtk2-doc
  python3-setuptools xfsprogs reiserfsprogs exfat-utils btrfs-tools
  libcanberra-gtk-module lightdm-remote-session-freerdp
  lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure remote-login-service metacity
  x-window-manager comgt wvdial
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcuda1-304-updates nvidia-304-updates nvidia-current-updates
  nvidia-libopencl1-304-updates nvidia-opencl-icd-304-updates
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apg aptdaemon aspell aspell-en avahi-utils bbswitch-dkms bluez cheese-common
  cracklib-runtime cups-pk-helper dbus-x11 dconf-cli desktop-file-utils dialog
  diffstat dnsmasq-base enchant evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-data-server-online-accounts
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common gcr gdisk geoclue
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip gettext gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0
  gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  gnome-bluetooth gnome-control-center-shared-data gnome-desktop3-data
  gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-menus
  gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-session-bin
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
  gstreamer1.0-clutter gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-x gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs
  hardening-includes humanity-icon-theme hunspell-en-us hwdata ibus ibus-gtk
  ibus-gtk3 im-config indicator-applet indicator-application
  indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages
  indicator-power indicator-session indicator-sound intltool-debian
  iputils-arping libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google libaccounts-glib0
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libarchive-zip-perl
  libarchive13 libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libasprintf-dev
  libauthen-sasl-perl libautodie-perl libavahi-glib1 libavc1394-0
  libcamel-1.2-45 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse
  libcanberra0 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdparanoia0 libcheese-gtk23
  libcheese7 libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango15
  libcogl15 libcrack2 libcroco3 libcuda1-331-updates libdbusmenu-glib4
  libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdigest-hmac-perl libdv4 libebackend-1.2-7
  libebook-1.2-14 libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
  libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libelfg0 libemail-valid-perl
  libenchant1c2a libfftw3-single3 libfile-basedir-perl libgconf-2-4
  libgcr-ui-3-1 libgdata-common libgdata13 libgee2 libgeoclue0
  libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0 libgles2-mesa libglib2.0-bin
  libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-desktop-3-7 libgnome-keyring-common
  libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8
  libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0
  libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common
  libgweather-3-6 libgweather-common libharfbuzz-icu0 libhunspell-1.3-0
  libibus-1.0-5 libical1 libicu52 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libindicator3-7
  libio-pty-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libipc-run-perl
  libipc-system-simple-perl libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblist-moreutils-perl
  libmailtools-perl libmbim-glib0 libmm-glib0 libmnl0 libmtp-common
  libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl
  libnet-libidn-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl libnet-ssleay-perl
  libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnettle4 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib-vpn1
  libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnotify4 libnspr4
  libnss3 libnss3-nssdb liboauth0 libopenobex1 liborc-0.4-0
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpam-gnome-keyring
  libpanel-applet-4-0 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libperlio-gzip-perl libproxy1 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulsedsp
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libqmi-glib0 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5
  libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5
  libraw1394-11 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsecret-1-0
  libsecret-common libshout3 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1
  libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt5-1 libsocket6-perl libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libsoup2.4-1 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libsub-identify-perl libsystemd-journal0
  libtext-levenshtein-perl libtheora0 libtimezonemap1 libudisks2-0
  libunistring0 libunity-control-center1 liburi-perl liburl-dispatcher1
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libwacom-common libwacom2 libwavpack1
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0
  libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-xkb1
  libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxklavier16 libyelp0 lightdm lintian
  mobile-broadband-provider-info modemmanager mousetweaks nautilus-data
  network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp
  network-manager-pptp-gnome notification-daemon nvidia-331-updates
  nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates nvidia-prime
  obex-data-server obexd-client p11-kit p11-kit-modules patchutils pptp-linux
  pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils python-cairo python-cups
  python-cupshelpers python-dbus python-dbus-dev python-gi python-gnomekeyring
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-libxml2 python-notify
  python-smbc python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-defer
  python3-pkg-resources python3-xdg rtkit session-migration
  signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-oauth2 signon-ui signond
  sound-theme-freedesktop system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev t1utils
  ubuntu-system-service udisks2 unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-settings-daemon
  usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data yelp yelp-xsl zenity zenity-common
0 upgraded, 351 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

*Whiskey Tango Foxtrot*...

This does **not** happen when I install `nvidia-current-updates`, so what gives?  Is there a way to install v331 without all this cruft?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run "sudo apt-get install (package name) --no-install-recommends" to install it without auto-installing any of the "dependencies" that ubuntu says are required, such as the full unity DE

Comment: Can't help suspecting that the long depends list is a bug.

Comment: I think it asks for the long list because the driver itself might be made specifically for unity, what with the hardware acceleration and such that has supposedly made it faster...

Comment: Ok, that might explain it.